# Are questions about news on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

The Bitcoin SE site has quite a number of questions asking for explanations of news articles and historic events, possibly because Bitcoin is so commonly misunderstood, but also because there have been many events of theft.

Sometimes such questions are tough to answer, but they can also be very useful for understanding the history.

Are questions about news/events on-topic here?

eg

- "How many people got on the waiting list for a Raspberry Pi in the first week?"
- "How did word spread so widely about the Raspberry Pi? Was it slashdotted?"

Comment: I expect both of those would be closed as "not constructive" rather than "off topic."

Answer (score 2):

I think we should keep it limited to software/hardware questions, and keep purchasing/supply/etc news at the source of the information - the foundation. If Raspberry Pi news is relevant in an answer, it should be included.

**On topic:**
Q: How can I install distro X?

A: Distro X is not currently supported, but is expected to be released mid 2013. (See the Raspberry Pi blog [here]).

In mid 2013, this answer should be updated to include information about how to install distro X.

**Off topic:**
Q: When is distro X going to be released?
Q: Why isn't distro X supported?

Answer (score 1):

As you said, news can aid the understanding of history and, therefore, why things are done the way they are. Many news articles on tech are ill-informed and vague and SE is a very good platform to seek clarification.

Comment: This is true -- but to be on topic I would argue that questions of this nature should be technical questions about the areas where the article was unclear.